# C# Automapper inner list from another inner list of different type

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I am trying to map something similar to this model:

```
class Source {
   ...
   SubSource subSource;
}

class SubSource {
   ...
   List<SourceListItem> list;
   SomeInfo someInfo;
   ...
}

class SomeInfo {
   string name;
   ...
}

class SourceModel {
   ...
   SomeInfoModel someInfoModel;
   ...
}

class SomeInfoModel {
   string name;
   List<SourceListItemModel> list;
   ...
}
```

What I need is to map "SubSource.List" to "SomeInfoModel.List". I am able to map every other property correctly, but the list is always empty after the mapping and no errors happen during execution.

I have the following configuration for the mappings:

```
CreateMap<SourceListItem, SourceListItemModel>()
CreateMap<SomeInfo, SomeInfoModel>()
CreateMap<Source, SourceModel>()
 ...
 .ForPath(dest => dest.someInfoModel.list, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
 src.subSource.list))
...
```

Comment: I think you should provide the definition of SourceListItem and SourceListItemModel classes

Comment: I can add them if needed, I simply skipped them because they're plain objects with simple properties (strings, ints and such)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing your code, the call to `configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` throws an exception where is clearly described the issue you are running into

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type.
>
> For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional
>   arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>
> SomeInfo -> SomeInfoModel (Destination member list) SomeInfo ->
>   SomeInfoModel (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties: list

You can refer to [the documentation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reproduce, but for me the mapping of `list` property works.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceListItem, SourceListItemModel>();
    cfg.CreateMap<SomeInfo, SomeInfoModel>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, SourceModel>()
        .ForPath(dest => dest.someInfoModel.list, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
         src.subSource.list));
    });

var source = new Source()
{
    subSource = new SubSource()
    {
        list = new List<SourceListItem>()
        {
            new SourceListItem() { Text1 = "text1" },
            new SourceListItem() { Text1 = "text2" },
        }
    }
};
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
var model = mapper.Map<SourceModel>(source);
```

The model used:

```
public class SourceListItem
{
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
}
public class SourceListItemModel
{
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What happen if you call `configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` ?

Comment: It says `list` property in `SomeInfoModel` is not mapped in the mapping SomeInfo -> SomeInfoModel, which is true.